# How to get HostName on Win7 Phone

Tags: networking, windows-phone-7, dns

Since I'm using Win7 Phone I can't simply use System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(). How am I supposed to communicate with another phone in this case?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`HostName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.nameresolutionresult.hostname%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)  property of `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.NameResolutionResult` class.

To asynchronously resolve the host-name use [`ResolveHostNameAsync(DnsEndPoint, NameResolutionCallback, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation.resolvehostnameasync%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) of `Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation.DeviceNetworkInformation` class.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do direct phone to phone communication unless your share the URI for raw push notifications.

The recommended approach to achieve this behaviour is to route the messages through a web server/service.